# Problemas accediendo a graphql en rails en heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Hola actualmente tengo una app en rails con graphql que funciona bien (solo tiene una vista) hasta que intento acceder a la ruta para graphiql en produccion (**ya que esta en heroku**), cada vez que intento acceder a la ruta en cuestion `url/graphiql`, si bien en un principio hace como que me toma la ruta esta se queda en loading, pero cuando reviso que error me muestra por consola aparece lo siguiente:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot use e "__Schema" from another module or realm.

Ensure that there is only one instance of "graphql" in the node_modules
directory. If different versions of "graphql" are the dependencies of other
relied on modules, use "resolutions" to ensure only one version is installed.

https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions

Duplicate "graphql" modules cannot be used at the same time since different
versions may have different capabilities and behavior. The data from one
version used in the function from another could produce confusing and
spurious results.
```

Buscando el error(no me aparecio mucho para rails) pero estos aconsejaban que agregara a package.json un script de `resolutions` y le pusiese la version para graphql.

Mi configuracion en routes para graph es: (actualmente volvi a hacer deploy quitando env)

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  #if Rails.env.development?
    #mount GraphiQL::Rails::Engine, at: "/graphiql", graphql_path: "/graphql"
  #end
  
  mount GraphiQL::Rails::Engine, at: '/graphiql', graphql_path: '/graphql'
  post "/graphql", to: "graphql#execute"
  mount ActionCable.server, at: '/cable'

  root 'static_pages#home'

end
```

y mi gemfile es:

```
gem 'graphql', '1.9.17'
gem 'graphiql-rails', '1.7.0', group: [:development, :production]
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.13'
```

Hasta ahora no he podido encontrar un error parecido al mio con heroku en una app con rails y graphql.

Comment: Verifica tu node module y que la dependecia este en el lugar indicado

Comment: Hola! Gracias x tu respuesta. Revise package json.lock para gems y dependencias. Node modules tambien se instala en rails (implicito) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso es un [bug abierto](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphiql-rails/issues/58) aun en la última versión.
Tus opciones son downgradear a la versión anterior a 1.5 donde se generó el bug:

```
gem 'graphiql-rails', '~> 1.4.11'
```

o agregar a tu archivo de `config/environment/production.rb`:

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
```

que [por lo que comentan](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphiql-rails/issues/58#issuecomment-530587848), puede aumentar bastante el tamaño final de tu archivo js resultante en producción, así que tampoco es la mejor opción.
Por último, simplemente desechar el cliente y usar alguno de [los que sugieren](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-playground) en [los comentarios](https://altair.sirmuel.design/).

Comment: Hola, gracias de nuevo por la ayuda. Efectivamente habia cambiado el archivo de production pero no pense que podria ser el problema de la gema tambien!